# Selecting non-highlighted rows in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have a long list of addresses and names on excel.  All the duplicate names and addresses have been highlighted.  I'm looking for a way to get the names that aren't highlight onto a mailing list in word, is there anyway of doing this short of selecting each individually?

Thanks in advance

Comment: sort by color, then you can copy without having to click on individual rows

Comment: How many columns do the duplicated name and addresses occur in?

Answer (score 0):

Using Excel 2007, filter for those not highlighted, copy visible and paste into Word.

By the way, no need to have highlighted duplicates, Sort & Filter - Advanced* could have extracted a list of uniques for you.

*

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the `Advanced Filter` feature? This would extract all items into a unique list, but this would include those that were originally duplicated. I don't think this matches the OPs requirement.

Comment: No I wasn't thinking of another list. The description `Unique Records Only` of the Advanced Filter is misleading. It will include ALL records, but then remove any that are duplicated. It doesn't just copy those rows which *only occur once*.

Comment: I don't have "Sort & Filter - Advanced" (unless you mean on the Data tab? - the Advanced Filter) in 2010 (or 2007). Perhaps you are using 2013? In the earlier versions, we can use AutoFilter, Filter by Color, and choose 'No Fill'.

Comment: Okay, no worries. Just seeking clarification ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming names are in column A and addresses in column B, then this formula added as a new column will have numbers 1, 2, etc., indicating how many times the combination of name & address repeats:

```
COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$6,A2,$B$2:$B$6,B2)
```

Enter this formula into, for example, C2 and copy it down.

From Word you can do a MailMerge, select the Excel file. As part of the MailMerge process you can filter the records to those where column C contains the value 1.

[image]